# Which of the two options will perform better?

Tags: php, mysql

Which of the two options will perform better, in MySQL?

a) One row, with 5 colums, one big (50kb) and 4 small (500b).

b) Two rows, one with 4 columns and one with 1.

The PHP reads the row very frequently, but needs only the small column information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're actually *selecting* the big column, it's unlikely it will have anything other than a little effect on the query.

There may be some *minimal* effect if the small rows aren't consecutive in the record (multiple disk reads to get the columns from the data section), or if it's part of a key being used to extract the data (multiple disk reads to extract the key), but that's likely to pale into insignificance next to all the other possible impacts on performance.

My advice is to followed third normal form and only worry about performance if it becomes noticeable (and only *when* it becomes noticeable - see YAGNI).

If the large column is naturally a part of the row based on 3NF, that's generally where it should go, not into a separate table. The issue of putting it into a separate table artificially is that your queries that need it and at least one of the other columns will be impacted because you have to do a join.

In any case, if you really want to know which of solution A or B is faster/smaller/better/stronger/more-elegant, you need to *measure* rather than guess (or ask us).

That involves trying both solutions in the likely *target* environment and actually evaluating how they perform. And, on top of that, database tuning is only a set-and-forget operation if neither your data not your schema ever change. Changes in either of those two may render your previous benchmarks irrelevant.